# No saved correctly JSON data sent by AJAX to laravel controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I'm building an application laravel 5.2, and I have a problem, the problem is that I only save the data from JSON, not the header information you see on the bottom. I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

**The Ajax** in the view

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'http://{!! $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] !!}/settings/languages_available/{!!$lang->id!!}/update_target',
          type: "put",
          data: {"target":""+JSON.stringify(data_rate)+""},
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
```

**The function** in the controller

```
 public function updateTargetLanguages(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $LA = LanguageAvailable::find($id);    
        $LA->target_languages = response()->json($request);
        $LA->save(); 
    }
```

**In the database is stored in this way:**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Content-Type:  application/json

 {"target":"[{\"title\":\"Brazilian Portuguese\",\"rate\":\"0.04\"},{\"title\":\"Belarusian\",\"rate\":\"0.06\"},{\"title\":\"Canadian French\",\"rate\":\"0.06\"}]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your setting the whole request. Try this:

```
$LA->target_languages = $request->input();
```

Comment: It is right now if I keep what I keep. thanks friend

Answer (score 0):

You have no need to use method as 'put'. If you want to use laravel put based route please set method as post and add an element with data as '_method' key. See the example

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'http://{!! $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] !!}/settings/languages_available/{!!$lang->id!!}/update_target',
          method: "POST",
          data: {"_method":"PUT", "target":""+JSON.stringify(data_rate)+""},
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
```

In route use this process or something like this

```
Route::put('your/route', 'YourController@updateTargetLanguages');
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks Nahid, the solution to my problem was to add:  $ LA-> TARGET_LANGUAGES = $ request-> input ();